# How to remove vertical space between divs in Bootstrap 3 grid layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

My Bootstrap 3 grid layout renders as follows:

[image]

However, I don't want the space between the 1st div (yellow) and the 3rd div (red).

Here's my code:

```
<div class='row'>   
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style='background-color:yellow;height:100px'>1st div</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style='background-color:blue;height:200px'>2nd div</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style='background-color:red;height:100px'>3rd div</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas please?

**UPDATE:**

I think I found the solution..

```
<div class='row'>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style='background-color:yellow;height:200px'>1st Div</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style='float:right;background-color:blue;height:600px'>2nd Div</div><br/><div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"  style='background-color:red;height:2000px'>3rd Div</div>
```

Comment: You can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/myHML/) but it won't be ordered correctly on small screens

Comment: I need to preserve the order on small screens

Comment: I don't think it can be done with only native bootstrap class. Create new ones instead.

Comment: I don't know why this question is downvoted, the order in responsive templates is very important.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but…

Your solution looks pretty good - in fact all you need is the `float: right;` on the blue div, but it works better in a media query, that way if you use other formations above 992px, the divs remain in the correct order:

html:

```
<div class='row'>   
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 yellow">1st div</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 blue">2nd div</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 red">3rd div</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.yellow {
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100px;
}
.blue {
    background-color:blue;
    height:200px;
}
.red {
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .blue {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/memeLab/M4P6g/1/

Comment: possibly easiest fix for this "issue" I've come across.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x=$('.row');
    $.each(x, function() {
        var max=0;
        $.each($(this).find('div[class^="col-"]'), function() {
            if($(this).height() > max)
                max=$(this).height();
        });
        $.each($(this).find('div[class^="col-"]'), function() {
            $(this).height(max);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Never use jQuery for this. CSS is enough